# Shopify delete customer graphql api

Tags: graphql, shopify

I want to implement a button on click it user will delete the user , for that we need graphql api , I got this documentation but it is not working on postman , https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-10/mutations/customerDelete

But it is not working it is saying customerDelete mutation does not exist , we use custom storefront api.

Answer (score 1):

Storefront API is NOT the same as the Admin API. To delete a customer you would be needing to make calls to the Admin API endpoint, with a valid token that has permission to delete customers. So the answer for you is to get yourself an Admin API token to use that mutation.